# Need help converting a process from Java(android) to IOS Swift

Tags: android, ios, swift, uiimage

Background: I have a process in an android application that resizes an image, uses JPEG compression of 30% from a bitmap, and returns a byteArray in which I convert to base64Encoded String. I need this type of functionality ported to IOS Swift if possible. I am undergoing information overload from the amount of methods on the web for image manipulation and I need some more direction.
here is my android code:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;

        try
        {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            //if the bitmap is smaller than 1600 wide, scale it up while preserving aspect ratio
            if(bmp.getWidth() < 1600) {
                int originalHeight = bmp.getHeight();
                int originalWidth = bmp.getWidth();

                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 1600,
                        originalHeight*1600/originalWidth, true);

                bmp = scaledBitmap;
                scaledBitmap = null;
            }

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos); // 30% compression
            image = baos.toByteArray();
        }
        //catch stuff after this
```

And here is my IOS Swift code so far:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    self.imgCheckFront.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage, 30.0)

    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)

    }

}
```

I think this is quite different than my Android process. The size of the resulting base64String I create in my IOS Code is way too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was a silly mistake.
this:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage, 30.0)
```

Needs to be this:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage, 0.3)
```